# quser (query user) no result in powershell c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I've been searching the solution of this problem for weeks now and still blocked...

I need to use the program "quser" in powershell but in my C# program.

If I run "quser" just in the powershell console I have a result.
But when I execute a powershell script with "quser", it returns nothing... That's weird.

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.Runspace = runspace;
        String script = "$re = '(\\S+)\\s+?(\\S*)\\s+?(\\d+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+\\s+\\d+:\\d+)'\n"
                            + "query user /server:"+machine+" | Where-Object { $_ -match $re } | ForEach-Object {\n"
                            + "New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{"
                            + "'Username' = $matches[1]\n"
                            + "'LogonTime' = $matches[6]\n"
                            + "}\n"
                            + "} | Select-Object Username, LogonTime | ForEach-Object { Write-Output (\"{0} is connected from {1}\" -f $_.Username, $_.LogonTime) }";
        ps.AddScript(script);
        Collection<PSObject> result = ps.Invoke();
        ps.Dispose();
        runspace.Close();
        runspace.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
```

The result of the ps.Invoke() is empty.
But when I run this code from a powershell console it works.

Also another weird thing, it works in remote powershell :

```
String script = "$re = '(\\S+)\\s+?(\\S*)\\s+?(\\d+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+\\s+\\d+:\\d+)'\n"
                            + "query user | Where-Object { $_ -match $re } | ForEach-Object {\n"
                            + "New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{"
                            + "'Username' = $matches[1]\n"
                            + "'LogonTime' = $matches[6]\n"
                            + "}\n"
                            + "} | Select-Object Username, LogonTime | ForEach-Object { Write-Output (\"{0} is connected from {1}\" -f $_.Username, $_.LogonTime) }";
        string shellUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
        System.Security.SecureString sString = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char passwordChar in password.ToCharArray())
        {
            sString.AppendChar(passwordChar);
        }
        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(username, sString);
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, machine, 5985, "/wsman", shellUri, credential);
        List<String> scriptOutput = new List<String>();
        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
        {
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipe.Commands.AddScript(script);
            Collection<PSObject> result = pipe.Invoke();
            foreach (PSObject line in result)
            {
                scriptOutput.Add(line.ToString());
            }
            pipe.Dispose();
            runspace.Close();
        }
        foreach(String line in scriptOutput)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

It returns the connected user.

The fact is that I don't want to logged into the machine in order to see the conncted users. (because it works in the powershell console)

If someone could help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use WMI? try the `Win32_PerfFormattedData_LocalSessionManager_TerminalServices` Class, it has TotalSessions and InactiveSessions Properties, if you need the full session data you can use the `Win32_PerfFormattedData_TermService_TerminalServicesSession` Class. it will save you all the text split work, and it's available remotely

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I tried both classes you suggested and I don't think I can retrieve the username of the active session. And I need to use "query user" because a gwmi request will need an authentication. With "query user" I don't need to be authenticated.